# Jquery trying to subtract value of tag from form input

Tags: jquery

hi I've got some elements in a form that contribute toward the value of an input field, additions are working perfectly but I'm having some problems with subtracting the values from the input field.

I have a AJAX confirm delete script up and running, on confirm it fires off an Ajax request to the a page which deletes a database record, once thats done I want to subtract a given value from that returned in an input field.

```
// Issue is to be deleted so modify the value in the outlay box
total = $("#CostToSolve").val();
$('.rec-outlay').closest(function() {
    total - (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0);
    });
$('#CostToSolve').attr("value", total + ".00");
```

Whenever I click delete it appends .00 to the input total, I've checked the variable 'total' in the console and it is returning the correct number so I'm presuming thats correct and guessing the issue lies solely with the syntax I've used in this line:

```
total - (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be return total - (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0); ?

Comment: is `closest()` a custom method, or are you using jQuery's `closest()` in the strangest way ever ?

Comment: lol yeah I was kinda guessing at that, I should have removed it. Perhaps I should use each instead.

Comment: `total -= (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0);` try with the `-=` operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var total = $("#CostToSolve").val();

$('.rec-outlay').each(function(i, ele) {
    total -= parseInt(ele.value,10) || 0;
});

$('#CostToSolve').val(total + ".00");
```

Comment: Tested and doesn't subtract the value, just appends .00.

Entering var total = $("#CostToSolve").val(); into the console returns undefined. Maybe its not catching that initial value.

Comment: ah but entering just 'total' into the console returns the correct value. Sorry, am still getting the hang of how the code inspector works

Comment: Hmm, yeah works on the jsfiddle site, not on mine though. Still just appends .00 odd

Comment: You're sure the elements have the correct ID's and classes etc, and you remembered the document ready function, jQuery and all the other common pitfalls we all manage to fall in from time to time ?

Comment: Ok I know what the problem is, my values are being returned in p tags atm, not inputs so parseInt(ele.value) will never return anything. I need to change back to text

Comment: Oh, ok, just change `ele.value` to `$(ele).text()`

Comment: OK Cool, have got it subtracting the values, now I just need to pick the closest value to the link clicked. Thanks for your help, it was invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

Segment:

```
$('.rec-outlay').closest(function() {
    total - (parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0);
    });
```

does nothing as you aren't inserting the result anywhere